# Add column to Entity framework databound datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

In my software, i made some entities:

```
public abstract class Product 
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
}
public class type1 :Product
{
    public int number{ get; set; }
    public string extradata{ get; set; }
    public bool uitgeleend { get; set; }
}
public class type2 : Product
{
    [Display(Name = "Merk en type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string extradata{ get; set; }
    public bool available{ get; set; }
}
```

To display this is a datagridview, i have this expression:

```
var results =db.producten.Where(c => c is type1|| c is type2).ToList();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = results;
```

The problem is, that EF put the extradata in the table as extradata for type1, and extradata1 for type2. When i want to add my extradata to my gridview by

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["extradata"].Visible = true;
```

i get a nullreferenceException, because type2 doesn't contain such a column. How can i display the column in my datagridview, without changing the entities too much?

Comment: If all products have a property 'string extradata' and a 'bool', where uitgeleend and available are just opposites, why not add them in your base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DataTable` for this purpose

Create a `DataTable` out of your List, Add more columns as you need, Bind `DataTable`
to `DataGridView`

you're done.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this i think:
Not sure just a little try:

```
var results =db.producten.Where(c => c is type1|| c is type2).ToList();
```

Comment: Hmm, what do you exactly mean? Isn't that also the current query?